# Distance between Listview items having Divider

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, margin

I got several questions on SO on this topic but all those are related to *Distance between Listview items* and almost all answers suggest to use **Transparent Divider** as solution.

But in my case, I already have divider between two list items, so how can I apply some margin/padding/distance between two list items?

Any help appreciated.

**Xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listMainPlans"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@drawable/list_divide"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Depends on what layout you exactly want to achieve. You can create/inflate custom list items and add the necessary padding/margin that you need in the XML.

Comment: This xml seems fine. About **margin/padding/distance**, you can leave padding/margin in row xml layout if you have prepared custom adapter for ListView.

Comment: you must be inflating a layout as the child layout.right??

Comment: @PareshMayani - I tried giving margin in row xml layout, but that doesn't get applied.

Comment: what is there in listview?? i mean what u r going to display in listview row??

Comment: Two textboxes, places side-to-side in a relative layout.

Comment: i was talking about this layout.just giving static height you will get distance between each row item

Comment: You need to give padding to your parent layout of the Row XML. That's it.

Comment: @MKJParekh - Yup, that worked...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based upon [this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429), you can add `padding` to the **listview_item_row.xml**.

Using your adapter you can inflate this xml for each element in your `ListView` (WeatherAdapter.java in the tutorial)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"> // <-----

     <ImageView  />

     <TextView  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It worked by setting padding top and bottom to the parent relative layout.

Comment: There's another way also: I can add a dummy textview with some fixed height.

Comment: Adding an empty `TextView` to build up a layout is not the best way to work :)

Comment: Yes, I knew this dummy textview approach but was looking for practical solution. Thanks a ton !

Comment: @Martin android:layout_alignParentTop="true"       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" works more efficient in relative layout than in linear layout.pls try it with relative layout

Answer (score 1):

Give static height to that relative layout such as:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_innerbg">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/item_background"
        android:minHeight="40dp">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>



    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
         android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You will get distance between each row item